# Transparent layer used in Tiny wings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

please can anyone show me how to implement using cocos2d, a half transparent layer that is tapped for game start like that obtained in the game called Tiny wings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a CCSprite to the scene then set the opacity to something less than 255 to make it translucent.

Here is some psuedo-code:

```
CCSprite* myTranslucentImage = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"touchMe.png"];
myTranslucentImage.opacity = 128;

[scene addChild: myTranslucentImage];
```

Comment: Thanks man but may I ask, is it possible to make only the translucent layer running without the layer in the background and other sprites running?

Comment: I would have to see what you mean in context.  There are ways to stop the movement and touch reception in the lower layers, if that is what you mean, but that would be a separate question that you need to provide some more info for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I think you are very close to what I am looking for. The picture is such that I have a scene that contains three layers(gameplay layer, hud layer and a transparent layer).Thus on game start, I want all the layers to be displayed but the topmost layer which is the transparent layer should be the only layer running while other layers below it are stopped and they only start when the transparent layer has finished its function. So all I want to know is how to stop some layers in a scene while allowing others to run on game start and not during the game.

Comment: Stopping a scene is dependent on what you mean by "stop".  As far as I know, there is no general purpose "stop" function for a layer, but you could pause all actions and stop all physics process, etc separately.  Figure out what it is you mean by "stop" and post some sample code in a new question, then I can help you out a bit more.

Comment: from your last reply, I mean to pause all actions and physics processes until after the countdown or the transparent screen is tapped which should  start the paused scene and resume all physics processes again. I have however posted another question with codes .Please see the topic - "CountDown Timer/ Transparent layer 2". Thanks

Comment: Hi man this is the code posted here at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545192/countdown-timer-transparent-layer-2).Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've never played Tiny Wings but I do know how to make a CCSprite transparent.

```
CCSprite *example = [CCSprite spriteWithImage:@"HelloWorld.png"];
[example setOpacity:160];
```

If you must use a CCLayer you should look at the Cocos2d documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot but what I want is making only this transparent layer active while the layer below which contains the main actions remains inactive until after the screen is touched. Do you know how this can be done?

Comment: You could use a boolean. if (myBoolean) { } else { }

Comment: I have tried using a boolean in my init method but nothing happens...can I ask is it possible to delay some layers within a scene from running and maybe have other layers running?

Comment: If you use the boolean in any input or updating methods, set it to false when the transparent scene shows, and set it to true when the screen is touched, it should work. Other than that, I'm not sure how something like this would be implemented.

Comment: from what you say, it means that having the boolean in the init method is wrong and I should instead have it in say, the udpdate or tick method...is that right?